# git-http-backend and ldap authentication, push error: requested URL returned error: 401 Authorization Required

Tags: git, apache, authentication, ldap

My setup:

OS: debian 
git v 1.7.10
apache (with suexec mode enabled) configuration with git-http-backend and ldap authorization to git repos wchich works for clone operations, but not working for push and that's the problem. I use https as communication protocol to my git server.
Here's my config:

**VirtualHost config:**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

    DocumentRoot /git/myrepos

    <Directory "/git/myrepos">
    Allow from All
    Options +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

ScriptAlias /git /git/myrepos/bin/suexec-wrapper.sh
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/git.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/git.key

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
```

**/git/myrepos/bin/suexec-wrapper.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH_INFO=$SCRIPT_URL
GIT_PROJECT_ROOT=/git/myrepos
REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
export GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL=true
/usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend
```

Cloning repos works as it should (eg. `git clone https://192.168.0.1/repo1.git`): it accepts credentials for ldap user and clone the repo.
And when pushing repo (eg. git push origin master): it asks for credentials, accept them and then throws error:

```
error: Cannot access URL https://192.168.0.1/repo1.git/, return code 22
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

When running push in verbose mode (`GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push origin master`) it asks for credentials, accept them and (tail of output):

```
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x1cdd270; (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x1cdd270; (connection #0)
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x1cdd270; (connection #0)
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* The requested URL returned error: 401
* Closing connection #0
* Expire cleared
error: Cannot access URL https://192.168.0.1/repo1.git/, return code 22
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

Am I configuring apache git-http-backend (with wrap script?) properly?
And what can cause the problem with push operation?
How to debug it more detailed way?
Any suggestions very appreciated!
Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries I've found the solution :)
The problem was in incorrect VirtualHost configuration for git-http-backend.
Here's my working config:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

        DocumentRoot /git/myrepos

        SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /git/myrepos
        SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
        ScriptAlias /myrepos/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend
        AliasMatch ^/myrepos/(.*/objects/[0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38})$ /git/myrepos/$1
        AliasMatch ^/repos/(.*/objects/pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}.(pack|idx))$ /git/myrepos/$1

        ScriptAliasMatch "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | info/refs | objects/(info/[^/]+ | [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/$1

        <Directory "/usr/lib/git-core/">
        Options +ExecCGI
        Allow From All
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/git.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/git.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown


<Location /repo1.git>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from all
AuthName "GIT Authentication"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
AuthLDAPBindDN domain\user
AuthLDAPBindPassword passwd
AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap.server:389/ou=git,DC=domain?sAMAccountName
Require ldap-group cn=git_repo1,ou=git,dc=domain
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Now all git operations works properly with git-http-backend via https with ldap authorization :)
 Maybe it will be useful for someone.